# Accessing a 3rd party camera app on Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm running Android 4.2 Jelly bean, and trying to build an app using Eclipse. The app I'm building requires access to a camera with burst mode features, which unfortunately the stock camera app does not have. However, there are several camera apps on the Play Store which provide this feature, such as "Bust Mode Camera". I was wondering if it would be possible to access this camera app (or such similar ones) from within my app, and use this instead of the default camera app?

I've tried to find a solution like this, but haven't been able to. I'd really appreciate some help with this. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) to get a list of installed apps, and see if the app you want is already installed.

If it isn't installed, then you can request the user install it from Google Play, and launch the app's page on Google Play for them. This will not work if that app isn't compatible with the user's device.

Once installed, you can simply launch is via a normal [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).